# render html string to React component via custom parsing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a html string fetched from server which looks like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>\n<img class="cover" src="someimg.jpg">\n<p>Introduction</p>
```

Now I want to transform the html with `<img class="cover" src="someimg.jpg">` part converted to my own React Component `<LazyLoadImg className="cover" src="someimg.jpg" />`.

Without server rendering or dangerouslySetInnerHTML, how do I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to fetch the entire HTML string? Couldn't you just fetch the class and src attributes and pop those into a React component at render?

Comment: Well, the people who build the back-end using ExpressJS with a WYSIWYG editor. So, at front-end I can only retrieve the results from the WYSIWYG editor parsed html string.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML string.

```
let responseText = '<h1>Title</h1>\n<img class="cover" src="someimg.jpg">\n<p>Introduction</p>';
```

Splitting the string by line breaks.

```
let splitter = /\n/;
let broken = responseText.split(splitter);
```

From here, it's a pretty simple task to strip out tags to get the stuff you really need.

```
broken[0] = broken[0].slice(4, broken[0].length - 5);
broken[1] = broken[1].slice(24, broken[1].length - 3);
broken[2] = broken[2].slice(3, broken[2].length - 4);
```

Boom.

```
console.log(broken); // [ 'Title', 'someimg.jp', 'Introduction' ]
```

Make sure all the above logic ends up in the right place within your component. I'm assuming that you received the original string via AJAX call. Probably put all that stuff in the callback.

Here's your component.

```
class ProfileSection extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{broken[0]}</h1>
        <LazyLoadImg className="cover" src={broken[1]} />
        <p>
          {broken[2]}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```